# Mongo query in array with maintaining order

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to make mongo query on array and give order in query?
What I'm looking for is something like e.g.:
Collection object - let's call it `Route` :

```
[{
  name: 'Route 1',
  start: ISODate('date'),
  stops: ['stop1Id', 'stop2Id', 'stop3Id', 'stop4Id']
},
{
  name: 'Route 2',
  start: ISODate('date'),
  stops: ['stop4Id', 'stop3Id', 'stop2Id', 'stop1Id']
}];
```

Now I'd like to make a query where I can specify that I want to go from `stop4Id` to `stop2Id`. Can I do something like this in one query?

```
Route.find({
  // where stop4Id.index < stop2Id.index
});
```

EDIT:
So as the result (from the example) it will return only second route. As the first has stops in opposite order.

Comment: Could you please explain bit more. ***query where I can specify that I want to go from stop4Id to stop2Id***?

Comment: Sure @AnthonyWinzlet what I meant is that results from query will have these stops in correct order. So in the example above it will return only the second route, because first has stops in opposite order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$indexOfArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) operator along with the  [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gt": [
      { "$indexOfArray": ["$stops", "stop2Id"] },       
      { "$indexOfArray": ["$stops", "stop4Id"] } 
    ]
  }
})
```

[**`Output`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cf5_abrx44p)

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "name": "Route 2",
    "stops": [
      "stop4Id",
      "stop3Id",
      "stop2Id",
      "stop1Id"
    ]
  }
]
```